# React-Navigation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string but got undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm getting an error while using StackNavigator of React-Navigation.

Following I'm showing you my code, the version that I have, and all my configuration of package.json

Here is the code:

```
import {React} from 'react'
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import LoginForm from '../view/screen/LoginForm'
import Setting from '../view/screen/Setting'

export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginForm },
  Setting: { screen: Setting }
});
```

This is my configuration:

```
 1. react-navigation@1.5.13 
 2. npm version: 5.6.0
 3. react-native-cli: 2.0.1
 4. react-native: 0.57.5
```

This is my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.5.9",
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.57.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-ui-lib": "^3.6.1",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.22",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
```

The error is show in the screenshot

[image]

The App.js is. The 21 line is the one with the Provider Component.
Look: without adding the StackNavigator I have no error.

```
import AppNavigator from "./routers/Router"

    render(){
        return (
            <Provider store={createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))}>
                <AppNavigator />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}



export default App;
```

Comment: Are `LoginForm` and `Setting` **default** exports or **named** exports?

Comment: show your App.js file

Comment: Something is wrong in line number 21 in your `app.js`. Can you post app.js file here?

Comment: @rickdenhaan they are export default

Comment: I added the App.js to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to change `export const` in AppsNavigator with `export default`.

```
export default AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginForm },
  Setting: { screen: Setting }
});
```