# HeaderBackButton gives error react-navigation-stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-stack

I upgraded react native project from 0.61.5 to 0.62.2 and since then got below error:

`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined`

Below is the code:

```
import { HeaderBackButton } from "react-navigation-stack";
return (<HeaderBackButton 
          label={params.lastScreenTitle} 
          labelStyle={{
            color:fontColor
          }}
          tintColor={fontColor}
          onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} />)
```

`react-navigation` version `4.1.0`

`react-navigation-stack` version `2.5.1`

Comment: react-navigation version ?

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar 4.1.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Navigation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string but got undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53681282/react-navigation-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-strin)